# Firebase OTP Verification Not Working for Google Play APP but working on Debug and release mode

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-play

The major problem is coming that OTP verification is not Responding the same way its responding on debug mode. even its working on play store for test numbers

```
@override
  Future checkOtp(String verificationId, String smsCode) async{
    try{
      showLoadingDialog();
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
      var result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
          .then((value) {
            var user = value.user;
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print(user);
              print(value);
            }
            if (value.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser == true) {
              Get.offNamed( RouteName.infoScreen,arguments: {
                "user":user
              });
            } else {
              Get.offNamed( RouteName.homeScreen,arguments: {
                "user":user
              });
              Utils.snackBar("Successfull", "Congrats on your successfully registration");

      }      return value;
          });
      return result;
    } catch(e){
      hideLoadingDialog();
      handler.handleFirebaseLoginErrors(e);
      bool result = false;
      if(e.toString()=="[firebase_auth/invalid-verification-code] The verification code from SMS/TOTP is invalid. Please check and enter the correct verification code again.") {
        Utils.snackBar("Invalid Otp", "Please Try with another otp.");
        result = true;
      }
      return result;
    }
  }`
```

This is my fucntion

I have already place all the SHA1 and SHA256 key from play store as well as from android studio.
in emulator its working perfect. even i cant find anything in logs expect this -

```
07:43:12.501 12725-12806 mali_winsys             com.updevelop.wellness_z_mvvm        D  EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2023-11-18 07:43:14.466 12725-12806 Surface                 com.updevelop.wellness_z_mvvm        D  Surface::disconnect(this=0x7a2bece000,api=1)
2023-11-18 07:43:14.469 12725-12725 View                    com.updevelop.wellness_z_mvvm        D  [Warning] assignParent to null: this = android.widget.FrameLayout{65c5d03 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-690,137}
2023-11-18 07:43:14.469  1332-1332  WindowManager           system_server                        V  mCurrentFocus: Window{ae17056 u0 com.updevelop.wellness_z_mvvm/com.updevelop.wellness_z_mvvm.MainActivity} newFocus Window{ae17056 u0 com.updevelop.wellness_z_mvvm/com.updevelop.wellness_z_mvvm.MainActivity}
```

when i try through google play store app.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue , the issue was in Automatic code detection from the devise. When OTP was automatically Detected then Manual OTP Was not working that is check OTP Function. you need to Navigate from Verification Complete in the function while you first send mobile number for verifications

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).